# MATLAB Figure Rendering: OpenGL vs. Painters?

Tags: matlab, opengl, matlab-figure

I'm clueless when it comes to which renderer to use for MATLAB figures or when it matters, but I have come across certain examples where it *does* matter:

```
plot(0,0,'ko','markersize',50,'linewidth',8);
set(gcf,'renderer','opengl');
set(gcf,'renderer','painters');
```

**Left=OpenGL, Right=Painters:**

[image: OpenGL result][image: Painters result]

(running Windows 7 Professional and MATLAB R2015b)

Are there times when using the OpenGL renderer produces better results than Painters? In general how do the two renderers differ?

Comment: Interesting question. Talking as a layman on graphics rendering who regularly has to produce publication-quality figures with MATLAB, a definitive answer to this one would be nice.

Comment: Read [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_renderer). Painters is usually faster. OpenGL makes a big difference in the quality of 3-D plots, especially if you're using lighting or transparency, or if you have a Retina display.

Comment: Is there a way to set "painters" as default for all plots? In R2016a the default is "opengl". EDIT: Found an answer: put `set(0, 'DefaultFigureRenderer', 'painters');` in `startup.m`.

Comment: The link by @horchler is broken, but a short explanation is given [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e283913).

Answer (score 1):

These are the differences I know of

- OpenGL is the default renderer
- OpenGL allows to plot transparency and Painter does not
- If there is a graphical bug when using OpenGL or if Matlab crashes, use Painter
- Select Painter to export figures in postscript format. Using OpenGL
  when the figure gets too complex, Matlab saves as Bitmap and you cannot edit it.

From the [Mathworks website (Scroll down to "renderer")](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e283913):

> - 'opengl' — OpenGL® renderer. This option enables MATLAB to access
>     graphics hardware if it is available on your system. The OpenGL
>     renderer displays objects sorted in front to back order, as seen on
>     the monitor. Lines always draw in front of faces when at the same
>     location on the plane of the monitor.
> - 'painters' — Painters renderer. This option works well for axes in a
>     2-D view. In 2-D, the Painters renderer sorts graphics objects by
>     child order (order specified). In 3-D, the Painters renderer sorts
>     objects in front to back order. However, it might not correctly draw
>     intersecting polygons in 3-D.

See also this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/resolving-low-level-graphics-issues.html) on fixing low level graphics issues with OpenGL.

Comment: I have added links.

Comment: so painters seem to use the CPU exclusively for rendering. In situations where Z-fighting might occur with opengl (e.g. plotting a 2d object in the same plot with a 3d plot object), painters appear to display surfaces consistently.