# Changing LineWidth messes up the marker

Tags: matlab, graphics

I am using Matlab 2017b. When I change the default line width, the circular marker becomes choppy, as if Matlab is 'out of ink'. The following code:

```
figure
subplot(211)
plot([1 2],[1 2],'o-','markersize',12)
xlim([0,3]), ylim([0,3])
subplot(212)
plot([1 2],[1 2],'o-','markersize',12,'linewidth',2)
xlim([0,3]), ylim([0,3])
```

produces this result:
[image]

**EDIT** Forgot to mention OS, win 10 64 bit

Comment: 2017a on Win7 x64 works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's one of those 'renderer' voodoo (in the sense that trial-and-error is the easiest approach), see this related question: [MATLAB Figure Rendering: OpenGL vs. Painters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742132/matlab-figure-rendering-opengl-vs-painters)

If I do this:

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters');
```

Then the marker looks as it should.